# How can I convert this list to a dataframe with same names in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data in R:

```
list0 <- list(ff = 45,gg = 23)
list1 <- list(a = 2, b=list0)
LIST <- list(mylist = list1)
```

I want to convert this list to a dataframe and get an output dataframe as follows, which has the following column header naming conventions:

```
  a b.ff b.gg
1 2   45   23
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vec <- unlist(LIST)
names(vec) <- sub("mylist.", "", names(vec))
dt <- data.frame(as.list(vec))

dt
  a b.ff b.gg
1 2   45   23
```

Answer (score 5):

The `LIST` step was unnecessary:

```
> data.frame(list1)
  a b.ff b.gg
1 2   45   23
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `do.call` with `data.frame` to construct the data.frame and include `unname` to drop the name of the first list level.

```
mydf <-do.call(data.frame, unname(LIST))

mydf
  a b.ff b.gg
1 2   45   23
```

Make sure that the object has the desired structure.

```
str(mydf)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a   : num 2
 $ b.ff: num 45
 $ b.gg: num 23
```